# business webpart on sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have a sharepoint standard edition. and yes it is by default that Business webpart is not given with the standard edition. 
Is there a way to buy this webpart and upload it to the standard edition of sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

No, because this web part is part of SharePoint 2010 enterprise license.

Technically, this is not only webpart you need but on the back end you need to turn on the features which are also part of EE. Even you get the webpart but still dependent features missing.